# I want to batch process with FIrestore + CloudFunctions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want an example code to add documents to multiple Firestore collections at once

This is an example of my Firestore structure.

```
{
   "users": {
      "UUID-1": {
         "list":[
            "text1",
            "text2",
            "text3",
            "text4",
            ...
         ]
      },
      "UUID-2": {
         "list":[
            "text1",
            "text2",
            "text3",
            "text4",
            ...
         ]
      }
      ...
   }
}
```

I want to put text in the list[] of all users in users

I read this article and wrote the following code.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

```
let batch = db.batch();
batch.set(
  db.collection('users').doc().collection(list),
    {
      unread: newUserId
    }
);

batch.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you. But why is "update" instead of "add"?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453776/how-to-add-a-new-field-to-all-current-documents-in-my-database and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079348/how-to-update-a-collection-using-cloud-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **You can execture multiple write operations as a single batch (or transaction) that contains two `set()` operations.**

**From the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) (I have not formally tested it myself):**

```
// Get a new write batch
let batch = db.batch();

// Set the value of 'John Doe'
let johnRef = db.collection('users').doc('UUID-1').collection('list');
batch.set(nycRef, {name: 'John Doe'});

// Set the value of 'Mary Thompson'
let maryRef = db.collection('users').doc('UUID-2').collection('list');
batch.set(maryRef, {name: 'Mary Thompson'}); 

// Commit the batch
return batch.commit().then(function () {
  // ...
});
```

Hope this helps.